# Is there a way to support widescreen resolutions in Battlefield 2?

Tags: pc, battlefield-2

I recently bought Battlefield 2, but I can't find a way to change the resolution to a widescreen resolution.

Is there a way to support widescreen resolutions (1920x1600 etc) in Battlefield 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this out recently, and all I could find was at WSGF but it works pretty well. Since then, this is [now officially fixed](http://widescreengamingforum.com/forum/5709/battlefield-2-widescreen-definitive-discussion-thread?page=43) in Battlefield 2 patch 1.5:

> I can confirm the latest Battlefield 2 patch (version 1.5) "fixed" the widescreen issues. Although the main menu and some HUD bars are stretched, and not in "proper" view.

Answer (score -1):

### Always go into the monitor settings along with the resolution settings of your operating system.

After connecting my PC to my living-room television, I was going back & fourth, before I did a " hand to the head" slap , and said to myself It's a monitor moron , it has an adjustment for wide-screen

Comment: Monitor can't add widescreen support to games aside from stretching.